# How can I get only responseText from response so I can use that dat using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery

I want only responseText from object so I can use the data to fill the fields.Here is my jquery Ajax code

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    type: "GET",      
    dataType: "application/json"
      }); 
  console.log(request);
```

In request there is responseText but am not able to retreive it I tried by using request.responseText then its showing as undefined so can help me how to get it am new to ajax and jquery

Comment: you could use the `success`, `error`, and `done` events to manipulate the response objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This will satisfy your req

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In console.log am able retreive data how can I use that response store it in a variable and use it globally so i can use data everywhere

Comment: In the success function use  response.userId, response.id, response.title,
response.body & store through variables. For eg: var UserId = response.userId, var Id = response.id...like this store the values you want!

Comment: Roy, if my Answer helped you out. Please Vote!

Comment: hi I dont want use datatype as jsonp how can I do it keeping datatype as json

Comment: then  use  dataType: "json"

Comment: if I use am unable to print it

Comment: i am using that. i can able to get. Copy & paste your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: "application/json", 
   error: function() {

   },
   success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
   }     
});
```

Comment: The response is printed in console

Comment: sry its not printing anything

Comment: you need to invoke the function.

Comment: @roy yes there was one mistake try the updated code above

Comment: @JayeshChitroda till same its not printing anything in console

Comment: but are you passing anything from ajax function ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a success/error function.

This is your call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1",
    type: "GET",      
    dataType: "application/json",
    // function goes here
});
```

That function will look like this:

```
success:function(details){
    // details is return data; assign to an object
}
```

Comment: Hi am new to jquery how can I add details please

Comment: can u just add in jsfiddle how to do it

Comment: 'details' is just a parameter which has it in the success callback already. So you do no need to declare it, you can call it any name you like, is based on your preference ;) .

Comment: @cst1992 Ah yes, I have edited the answer. Thanks for the detailed explanation. ;)

Comment: @roy btw, you can't alert/console.log() when you have a type:json, if you want to know the returned string, use console.log(JSON.stringify(details)) and turn off the type:json.